# Touch keyboard lacks autocorrect, Word Flow, etc. in certain apps and text fields

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, keyboard, tablet, on-screen-keyboard

The touch keyboard in Windows 10 has some pretty great features such as autocorrect and Word Flow, but as far as I can tell, the only place where both of these features work is Discord on Edge.

In Sticky Notes, Word, and most other websites in Edge, Word Flow works, and the keyboard shows word suggestions on the top, but there's no autocorrect. In Chrome and Sublime Text, there's no word suggestions, autocorrect, *or* Word Flow. [Here's what I'm experiencing with Word Flow:](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-touch/w10-fall-creators-update-wordflow-keyboard-not/512fad87-4f33-49ab-ae59-a129d78941c8)

> Swiping a word creates a trail on the keyboard, but it doesn't result in any words in the document.  Strangely, when I type letters one-at-a-time, on the same Word Flow keyboard, they appear in the document.

The answer a Microsoft Agent gives is:

> If you are using the Narrow keyboard in one of these languages, and you see a trail after swiping but no text is generated, you may be trying to use shape writing in an experience not supported by the feature. It currently may not work as input for things like password fields, Excel, or Chrome. If you want to test whether the feature works at all, open Sticky Note and try to use the feature there.

It's rather frustrating for me that autocorrect and Word Flow don't work in so many apps. How can I enable these features even when the specific app or text field apparently isn't configured to support them?

Answer (score 1):

#### Autocorrect and Word Flow don't work in so many apps.

Autocorrect only works if the app has been built to use the Windows Spell Checking API. I think that Word Flow has a similar requirement.

> It works in some universal apps (especially built-in apps like Edge
>   and popular apps like Facebook), but not in others. It’s up to app
>   developers whether they want to use the Windows Spell Checking API or
>   not. **Autocorrect doesn’t work on most traditional desktop apps at
>   all**. It can even interfere with other spellchecker apps or services
>   you might have installed, such as Spell Check Anywhere or Grammarly.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Source [How to disable auto-correct and highlighted misspelled words in Windows 10 | Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-spell-checker-windows-10)